# Xampp working on IE but not on Firefox

Tags: xampp

I have recently started to work with Xampp. But now whenever I try to access localhost, I get a blank screen on Firefox/Chrome, but it works fine in Internet Explorer. Please help?

Thanks.

Comment: can you access via http://127.0.0.1?

Comment: No, it shows the same blank screen.

Comment: It worked. Had to 'bypass the proxy server'.